# Can not set Long field com.spitSpring.HiberanateHQL.hibernate.entity.Employee.id to com.spitSpring.HiberanateHQL.hibernate.entity.Employee

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

### I am working on project consisting of Hibernate + Spring Boot. I have created a function to insert data into the table but it gives me error while doing so.

I have uploaded the link to the project on github
[Error_Hibernate](https://github.com/rishilin09/error_hibernate/tree/main)

Please can you tell me how to implement the function for inserting data into table through Hibernate

Images are given below
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju6RR.png) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdylX.png)